# setting up login throttle using username and not ip address

Tags: laravel

Hi i have been following this article on how to create a login throttle in laravell -> https://webomnizz.com/integrate-throttle-in-custom-login-using-laravel/

this all works fine the only using:

```
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
```

The problem i am having is that this is IP based. I have a front end and a backend so when a user makes 3 failed attempts to login, it throttles the entire frontend at that IP.

is there a way i can increment the login attempts based on the username and not on the ip specifically. or do i have to handle this using separate tables with increments?

Comment: It does not use only IP, it uses a combination of IP + Username. If you implement only Username, you might be blocking the `valid user to login` from a one location, when a `bruteforce attempt` for that same user was used from different IP/Location

Comment: the only problem i am having is my ip address is always the same as the requests are coming from my front end server so the user name is the only variant. i tried logging in with separate users but as soon as the first user gets throttled the others cannot login aswell.

Comment: I would say you have another problem, if you are not logging the actual visitor IP .. Resolve that first, and you will solve your issue above, AND you will have a much better visibility on who is trying to login via which IP..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i sorted this out. The problem i was having is that my throttleKey was not detecting the username value and it was being set to just the visitor ip address.This was a problem as most of the users use the same wifi and sometimes have the same IP address. so i was getting something like this:

```
|127.0.0.1
```

what i did was added a throttle key function in my auth controller to override the default throttlekey and specify my own throttle key to use

```
protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
  {
       if (Config::get('auth.throttle_key') == 'ip') {
           return $request->ip();
       } else {
           return Str::lower($request->username).'|'.$request->ip();
       }
  }
```

i hope this helps whoever gets this issue in the future